# MultiindexなSeriesを表形式に変換する方法

Tags: python, pandas

以下のようなデータがあります。

sample code:

```py
import pandas as pd

arrays = [np.array(['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux']),
          np.array(['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two'])]

s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(8), index=arrays)

print(s)
```

output:

```
bar  one   -0.431204
     two   -0.476479
baz  one   -0.758383
     two   -0.263379
foo  one   -0.353537
     two   -0.202995
qux  one   -0.774872
     two   -0.011614
dtype: float64
```

このデータを

```
    one    two
bar -0.43  -047
baz -0.75  -0.26
foo ...    ...
qux ...    ...
```

のような形式にするためにはどうすればよいでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unstack(level=-1)`を使えば出来るでしょう。
ちょうど類似の説明がドキュメントに書いてあります。
[pandas.Series.unstack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html)

質問内容に適用すれば以下のようになるでしょう。

```
s = s.unstack(level=-1)
```

結果

```
          one       two
bar -0.431204 -0.476479
baz -0.758383 -0.263379
foo -0.353537 -0.202995
qux -0.774872 -0.011614
```

ちなみに何故かマイナスではない`(level=1)`でも同様の結果になるようです。
そして`0`と`-2`が同じ結果で以下のようになり、`-3`と`2`はエラーになりました。

```
            bar       baz       foo       qux
one   -0.431204 -0.758383 -0.353537 -0.774872
two   -0.476479 -0.263379 -0.202995 -0.011614
```

---

小数点以下の桁数を変更する場合、表示する値そのものの変更は`round()`等で、値は変えずに表示形式だけ変更するなら`display.float_format`で変えられるようです。
[pandasで数値を丸める（四捨五入、偶数への丸め）](https://note.nkmk.me/python-pandas-round-decimal/)
[Pythonで小数・整数を四捨五入するroundとDecimal.quantize](https://note.nkmk.me/python-round-decimal-quantize/)

[pandasの表示設定変更（小数点以下桁数、有効数字、最大行数・列数など）](https://note.nkmk.me/python-pandas-option-display/)

ただし変更後の数値がどのようになるかは、それぞれの処理方法や指定によるでしょう。